# subgraph of the graph of a polytope

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, polytopes

Take a polytope $P$ and $G(P)$ it's corresponding graph. And $H$ a subgraph of $G(P)$ which is the graph of a polytope $\tilde{H}$. Does this imply that $\tilde{H}$ is a face of $P$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take a double pyramid over the cycle $C_4$. The subgraph induced by the cycle is the graph of a polytope, but is not a face.